# instanceof operator

Tags: java

Why is `Foo[]` `false` ?. It is an instance of `Bar`. Even `Face` is valid as `Bar class` implements it.Two objects of the same class also work fine with `instanceof.`

Operands and Results Using instanceof Operator.

```
First Operand              instanceof Operand             Result
```

(Reference Being Tested) (Type We’re Comparing 
                              the Reference Against)

```
null                   Any class or interface type        false
Foo instance                 Foo, Bar, Face, Object       true
Bar instance                 Bar, Face, Object            true
Bar instance                     Foo                      false
Foo [ ]                      Foo, Bar, Face               false
Foo [ ]                         Object                    true
Foo [ 1 ]                    Foo, Bar, Face, Object       true
```

Comment: We have no idea what those diagnostic lines show. Please provide a short but complete example.

Comment: what does "Foo [ ] Foo, Bar, Face    is false" mean?

Comment: That new edit doesn't make it any easier to understand. Why don't you just show us the actual code you're using to compare everything.

Comment: A `Foo[]` (array of `Foo`) is ofcourse not a `Foo`, a `Bar` or a `Face`, so it's not surprising that `instanceof` returns `false`.

Comment: @Jesper: you may be up to something here. +1 for your powers of divination/decoding

Comment: Sorry for the trouble :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo[]` is an **array** of `Foo` objects. An array of `Foo` objects is not a `Foo`, `Bar` or `Face` object, so if you check that with `instanceof`, the result will be `false`. Arrays *are* objects in Java, so `Foo[] instanceof Object` is `true`.

`Foo[1]` refers to the `Foo` object at index 1 in the array. The type of that object is `Foo`, so if you check that with `instanceof`, the result is `true` for `Foo`, `Bar`, `Face` and `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> (Reference)               (Type)                          (Result)
> Foo [ ]                   Foo, Bar, Face                  false
> ```

`Foo[]` means "array of Foo", and a `Foo[]` is not a subtype of `Foo`, `Bar` or `Face`.

> ```
> Foo [ ]                   Object                          true
> ```

However, `Foo[]` is a subtype of `Object`, because all reference are subtypes of `Object` and an array type is a reference type.

> ```
> Foo [ 1 ]                 Foo, Bar, Face, Object          true
> ```

`Foo[1]` means (I presume) the second element of a `Foo[]` instance.  The notional type of an element of a `Foo` array is `Foo`.  And `Foo` *is* a subtype of all of those types.

> ```
> null                      Any class or interface type     false
> ```

The `null` value is not an instance of *any* reference type in the technical sense.  (When you assign `null` to a reference variable, the `null` literal is *converted* to the type of the reference variable ...)  This case is a little bit unexpected (for new Java programmers), but it is how the `instanceof` operator is specified to work.

Comment: `Foo[1]` is the *second* element of the array (indices start at 0).

Comment: @Jesper - nit-picker :-)